# Peticion POST con datos filtrados mostrados en datatable - Jquery

Tags: jquery, json, datatables, post

Tengo problemas para mostrar la informacion filtrada en un POST y no se cual sea el error, estoy siguiendo las indicaciones de la pagina oficial de Jquery para uso del POST pero al tratar de mostrar la data en el datatable solo me aparece un object:Object, ayuda por favor.

Gracias!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <title>Prueba datatable</title>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var table = $.post( "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",{userId:"3"}, function( data ) {



        table.done(function( data ) {
          alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
        });
        alert( "success" );
        table.done(function() {
          alert( "second success" );
        })
        table.fail(function() {
          alert( "error" );
        })
        table.always(function() {
          alert( "finished" );
        });


        $('#data-table').DataTable({
         "data" : data,
         columns : [
         {"data" : "userId"},
         {"data" : "id"},
         {"data" : "title"},
         {"data" : "body"}
         ]
       });

      });



    });

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

   <table id="data-table" class="table table-bordered" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>userId</th>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>title</th>
        <th>body</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>


  </table>

  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: Tu var data es un objeto. Conviértelo a un array para que DT pueda cargarlo a tu tabla.

Comment: disculpa no habia subido la version final de mi pregunta ya habia puesto un var en el objeto del table, asi es como recibo un object Object.

Comment: Pregunto, no te sería más fácil con "FormData" y usando ajax?, al menos a mi parecer es más sencillo.

Answer (score 0):

El post que estas generando es un [diferido](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/). Hay que ajustar tu estructura.
La configuración la puedes asignar solo una vez.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   initTable();
   setDataTable();
});
function initTable(){
    $('#data-table').DataTable({
     columns : [
     {"data" : "userId"},
     {"data" : "id"},
     {"data" : "title"},
     {"data" : "body"}
     ]
   });
  });
}
```

Y al momento de cargar tus registros, hazlo dentro de los estatus del diferido.

```
function setDataTable(){
    let table = $.post( "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",{userId:"3"});
    table.done(function( data ) {
         AddRows($('#data-table'), data);
    });
}
```

Voy a agregarte un par de funciones que utilizo para llenar las tablas en datatable. De esta manera puedas trabajar con la data de la tabla.

```
function AddRows(tbl, lst) {
    dt = tbl.DataTable();
    dt.clear().draw();
    for (let i in lst)
        if (lst.hasOwnProperty(i))
            AddRow(dt, lst[i]);
}
function AddRow(dt, obj) {
    dt.row.add(obj).draw(false);
}
```

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta, por mi falta de experiencia en javascript(jquery) no se muy bien como organizar tus sugerencias, he tratado de hacerlo pero aun no son mostrados los datos, dejo mas abajo como lo hice.

Comment: Agrego que me dice que no tengo permiso CORS, me han sugerido usar jsonp, si esta es la solucion como la plantearia?

Comment: Revisa tu web.config para ver que tipo de datos permite cargar a través de los gets y post que realices.

Comment: La sugerencia del json,¿lo está haciendo el en back o en el front?

Comment: En el back, al parecer debo usar un jsonp con los permisos requeridos tu solucion es la correcta, solo debo cambiar a jsonp y usar correctamente la configuracion para que muestre la data.

Gracias por todo!

Comment: Excelente. Si es correcta puedes marcarla la solución para futuras referencias.

Answer (score 0):

Asi estoy intentando mostrar tu ejemplo Aaron.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <head>


      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css"/>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <title>Stack</title>

        <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
            initTable();
            setDataTable();
            });

          function initTable(){
                $('#data-table').DataTable({
                   columns : [
                    {"data" : "userId"},
                    {"data" : "id"},
                    {"data" : "title"},
                    {"data" : "body"}
                   ]
              });
              };

             function setDataTable(){
             let table = $.post( "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",{userId:"3"});
              table.done(function( data ) {
             $('#data-table').DataTable().data = data;
                });
                };

      </script>
  </head>
  <body>



    <table id="data-table" class="table table-bordered" width="100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
          <th>userId</th>
          <th>id</th>
          <th>title</th>
          <th>body</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>


       </table>

      </body>

      </html>
```